# Prove that there is a maximum subset of $\mathbb{N}$ who is closed under summation and does not contain any prime number.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, maxima-minima

Prove that there is a maximum subset of $\mathbb{N}$ who
is closed under summation and does not contain any prime number.

My work:

Idea is to use [Zorn lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zorn%27s_lemma). Let $F \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ be set of all such set with given properties. We also must see that $F$ isn't an empty set - for example in my set theory class we include $0\in \mathbb{N}$ so $F=\{0\}$ is one example. 

 Let $L$ be an arbitrary nonempty chain in $F$. We know that upper bound of chain $L$ is union of all elements in $L$.

 But Zorn lemma told us that upper bound has to be in $F$. So we need to check this property first.
Let $L_1$ and $L_2$ be arbitrary set from our chain L.
L is chain and that implies that $L_1  \subseteq  L_2$ or $L_2  \subseteq  L_1$.
Without loss of generality we can assume that $L_1  \subseteq  L_2$. 
 Ok, but I stuck here because I have no idea how to prove that union holds given properties.

Comment: Don't use Zorn's lemma. It is completely unnecessary. Rather, proceed by a recursive construction: you build sets $F_0\subset F_1\subset\dots $ and their union is the set you want. Start with $F_0=\{0\} $. Given $F_n $ let $k $ be the least natural not in $F_n $ such that there are no primes in the closure of $F_n\cup\{k\} $ under addition, and let $F_{n+1} $ be this closure. If no such $k $ exists, you are already done. At the end you are done since any 2 members of the union are in some $F_n $, so their sum is in there as well, and no prime was ever added. No need for Zorn's lemma.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo What about the set of all even integers excluding $2$ ? isn't that an even simpler solution ?

Comment: @Ewan Yes indeed. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. The final blow is a classic in applying Zorn's lemma: pick any two elements from the union and argue that there has to be *one* of the $L_i$'s in which they both lie. Therefore so does their sum.

As for the primes, that is easier to see.

Answer (score 1):

The maximal subsets of $\mathbb N$ that are closed under addition and contain no primes are exactly
$$ p\mathbb N\setminus\{p\} = \{ 0, 2p, 3p, 4p, 5p, \ldots \} $$
for prime $p$.

To see that these *are* maximal, note that if an addition-closed set contains two coprime numbers $a$ and $b$, it [will contain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem) every number greater than $ab-a-b$, which means that it can't be prime free.

On the other hand, suppose we have a prime-free addition-closed set. The gcd of this set must (by the above argument) be greater than $1$ and therefore all elements of the set have a prime factor $p$ in common, and therefore it is contained in $p\mathbb N\setminus\{p\}$.

Comment: Nice and clean.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think Zorn's lemma is really needed here. Assume that $E\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ is closed with respect to $+$ and let $m=\min E$. Then $E$ contains $m,2m,3m,4m,\ldots$ and if $\mathcal{P}\cap E=\emptyset$ we have that $m$ is a composite number. If $E$ also contains some number which is coprime with $m$, then $[N,+\infty)\subset E$ for some $N\in\mathbb{N}$ by Bézout's lemma, contradicting $\mathcal{P}\cap E=\emptyset$. In particular any two elements of $E$ share a common divisor greater than $1$ and any $E$ fulfilling the given constraints is an AP (arithmetic progression) of the $k\mathbb{N}$ form with some elements dropped. The actual meaning of *maximum* in the original question is not crystal clear to me, but in any case it is not difficult to deal with lacunary APs.